# How to Undo the "Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL" in NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, compression, source-code

I am using **Notepad++** for my coding , just used the their

```
Edit > Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL
```

feature to remove the space and tabs and compressed the code , but how do i UnDo it ?

is there any way to get the code back to normal view/with spaces and tabs with hierarchy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Ctrl-Z to Undo it?  Otherwise it has no idea what was removed or where it would need to be put back -- it can't guess. ;)

Comment: i meant, after saving the file and opening again the saved compressed file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a language with explicit line endings such as `;`, you can easily use find'n'replace with `;/n`

If you have nested structures with `if/endif` or `{}` you can easily search and tab those.

The real trick is keeping track of nesting and indenting based on nested levels. I am sure there is a regex you can come up with, but honestly, you are programming: try writing a simple text process routine which reads in the file and handles your rules.

It is probably faster than googling for a plugin.

Comment: its php file, with mixed code, html,javascript,css,php